# Python:reemplazar los valores de una tabla a partir de un diccionario

Tags: python, sqlite

Tengo una tabla llamada Piezas:

```
               class Piezas(Model):

                   Nombre = CharField()
                   Numero_registro_piezas = CharField()
                   Fecha_fabricacion = IntegerField()
                   Fabricante = CharField()
                   Localidad_de_fabricacion = CharField()
                   Precio = IntegerField()
                   Numero_piezas_vendidas = IntegerField()

                   class Meta:
                       database = db

               db.connect()
               db.create_tables([Piezas, Fabricante, Ordenes,VentasIntermediario])
               db.close()
```

La cual he rellenado y en otro archivo de python obtengo un valor de diccionario (valor) como este:

```
               {'Queso': 21}
```

Me gustaría iterar los valores de keys del diccionario sobre la columna de la tabla Precio.Nombre y cambiar los valores de la columna de la tabla Precio.Numero_piezas_vendidas
He intentado cambiar los valores de la tabla relacionandolos con el diccionario de esta manera:

```
               prueba = Piezas.get(Piezas.Nombre == valor.keys())
               prueba.Numero_piezas_vendidas = valor.values()
               prueba.save()
```

Cuando hago unn print de la función get de la tabla:

```
               prueba = Piezas.get(Piezas.Nombre == valor.keys())
```

obtengo este resultado

```
                1
```

Pero obtengo este output:

```
         Proyecto_final.Proyecto_models.PiezasDoesNotExist: <Model: Piezas> instance matching query does not exist:
         SQL: SELECT "t1"."id", "t1"."Nombre", "t1"."Numero_registro_piezas", "t1"."Fecha_fabricacion", "t1"."Fabricante", "t1"."Localidad_de_fabricacion", "t1"."Precio", "t1"."Numero_piezas_vendidas" FROM "piezas" AS "t1" WHERE ("t1"."Nombre" = ?) LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
         Params: ["dict_keys(['Queso'])", 1, 0]
```

¿En que estoy fallando? ¿Cómo puedo relacionar los valores de la tabla con el diccionario y una vez relacionados cambiarlos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La llamada a `valor.keys()` te devuelve una lista con las claves del diccionario. Aún si el diccionario sólo tiene una clave, como es tu caso, lo que obtendrás es una lista (en realidad, siendo aún más exactos, devuelve un objeto de tipo `dict_keys()`, pero se comporta como una lista pues puedes iterar sobre sus valores, en todo caso no te devuelve una clave que es lo que tu código presupone).

Lo mismo ocurre con `valor.values()` que te devolverá una lista con los valores asociados a las claves, y no un valor particular.

El método más genérico para tu caso, por si acaso el diccionario tiene varias claves y valores, sería iterar por los ítems del diccionario y para cada uno de ellos hacer la modificación que necesitas en tu tabla.

No he entrado a comprender tu modelo de datos o las operaciones con el ORM, pero basándome en el código que suministras creo que algo como esto debería funcionar:

```
for nombre, vendidas in valor.items():
   prueba = Piezas.get(Piezas.Nombre == nombre)
   prueba.Numero_piezas_vendidas = vendidas
   prueba.save()
```

Comment: SIIIIIII! funciona. Muchas gracias @abulafia No sabía que se podía nombrar así al diccionario para iterarlo sobre la tabla. Funciona correctamente. Muchas gracias